# How do we load an angular component's styles into an iframe?

Tags: angular, typescript, iframe

I'm working on a component that renders other components into an `iframe`.  It renders successfully however I noticed the styles aren't being passed into it. I tried using the `styles` array in the `@Component` instead of linking to an external stylesheet which failed.  I also added them to the template inside of a `<style>` tag which also failed.  I see how we can access the `contentDocument` and or `contentWindow` to pass data into the DOM of the `iframe` which I planned on using a `service` to do instead of having to dig around at things I can't even touch once they're inside the `iframe`.  Is there a way to pass the styles into it without having to make a data object then a couple functions inside the nested component to create and apply them?  So far this is what my code looks like.

**Component**

```
import { PropertyDisplayComponent } from './components/property-display/property-display.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'responsive-shell',
  templateUrl: './responsive-shell.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./responsive-shell.component.css']
})

export class ResponsiveShellComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('compFrame', {static: false}) CompFrame: ElementRef | undefined;
  doc: any;
  compRef: ComponentRef<PropertyDisplayComponent> | undefined;

  constructor(private VcRef: ViewContainerRef, private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  public onLoad(){
    this.doc = this.CompFrame?.nativeElement.contentDocument || this.CompFrame?.nativeElement.CompFrame.contentWindow;
    this.createComponent();
  }

  private createComponent():void{
    const compFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(PropertyDisplayComponent);
    this.compRef = this.VcRef.createComponent(compFactory);
    this.compRef.location.nativeElement.id = 'propertyDisplay';
    this.doc.body.appendChild(this.compRef.location.nativeElement);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit():void{
    this.onLoad();
  }

}
```

**Template**

```
<section class="shell">
    <iframe class="iframeShell" #compFrame></iframe>
</section>
```

Is there something I should be doing differently or does anyone see where I can add in the stylesheet?

**UPDATE**
I discovered the styling works if we do it inline, but would prefer a different solution if we can just pass the stylesheet some type of way.

Comment: Hi, it depend on if the Iframe is on the same origin. Could you complete your question with this information ? (and short answer, if this isn't in the same origin, this wont be doable, you'll have to work with [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage))

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "on the same origin"?  I import the `PropertyDisplayComponent` into the `ResponsiveShellComponent` which uses the `iframe`.  Both components are also part of the same module.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: No, not really. Since iframe is loading an external content, to be able to change the css inside this Iframe, this would require to have the same origin. Meaning "your website: `first.my-website.ch` and the iframe `second.-my-website.ch`. Is it clearer ? If yes, do you have the same origin ?

Comment: ... well, styling iframe wouldn't do for cross-domain iframe, next, consider Angular's `ViewEncapsulation` (maybe try to set `ViewEncapsulation` to `none` and rather apply styles with `document.head.appendChild(cssStyles)` ...

Comment: @RaphaëlBalet oh you mean like that, yes they are both a part of the website I'm building, which is how I'm Passing the component into the iframe rather than setting the `src` of the iframe to point to another website.

Comment: @Vovan_Super I'm not trying to style the iframe itself.  I'm passing a component inside of it and the styles for that component aren't being passed in for some reason, so I want to figure out how to style the component inside the iframe.

Comment: Can you provide me one last information? I would like to now, if you're using it into the same project, why do you even try to use an iframe. After that I think I'll be able to test out and provide you more information :)

Comment: yes they are part of the same project.  I created a new css framework and I'm making the doc pages to teach people how to use it.  I want to use the iframe because it has it's own DOM which will make the elements scale according to the size of the `iframe` where if I just do it inside a `div` it wouldn't work because the elements will scale according to the browser window rather than the size of the `div`.  Using an `iframe` basically creates a browser window inside the browser and by dragging the size of the iframe the elements inside of it will scale accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the component decoration from this...

```
@Component({
  selector: 'responsive-shell',
  templateUrl: './responsive-shell.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./responsive-shell.component.css']
})
```

to this...

```
@Component({
  selector: 'responsive-shell',
  templateUrl: './responsive-shell.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./responsive-shell.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
```

[More on the topic of ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation).

Note: this [only works for modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/shadowdomv1) because it relies on the browser's support for the Shadow DOM API. I've experienced wonky behavior if you are loading several SCSS files from your component's SCSS but local styles work well.

Comment: I actually figured that out quite some time ago and totally forgot to post the answer and select it lol.  Thanks for the reminder.